# How can I insert string value that includes a special char like ', ", /, - , +, =, dst?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `BasicInfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

How to insert `Category` and `Description` that user inputs which includes a special char like `'`, `"`, `/`, `-`, `+`, `=`, dst, without syntax error? Doing so I get:

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 'S',3)'

Comment: Make sure you are using prepared statement in your update / insert queries and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the language you were using to do the insert.
You need to escape the `'` by using a `\` in front of it. Like this
`thank\'s`

Further to this like Ken Lee suggested it's highly recommended to use prepared statements with parameters for your queries.